# Android. Как разместить на Canvas - кнопку

Tags: android

Так как этот холст занимает всю область экрана, как на нем разместить например - кнопку?

Вот код с примера, что и куда нужно дописать, чтоб на экране появилась кнопка:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawView(this));
    }

    class DrawView extends View {

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить кнопку в класс DrawView:

```
private Button mButton;
```

Нарисовать ее в onDraw(Canvas canvas):

```
mButton.setBounds(startX, startY, endX, endY); //параметры определяют область, где будет нарисована кнопка
mButton.draw(canvas);
```

Конечно, предварительно, нужно разместить на кнопке какой-то текст и задать цвет/фон через setText() и setBackground().